# How to open AppSync GraphQL to public?

Tags: graphql, aws-appsync

I've been trying to enable public access to appsync graphql, but had no luck.

Within the authorization, it needs cognito/api key/iam setup.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using Amplify?

Comment: no, im not using amplify

Answer (score 0):

From the [AppSync Developer Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/security.html), it is recommended to use `api key` when you want a public api:

> API Keys are recommended for development purposes or use cases where it’s safe to expose a public API.